# iOS blocks, how to use in different implementation files

Tags: ios, block

I am trying to make some reusable blocks for my application.

**CommonBlocks.h**

```
void (^testBlock)(int) = ^(int number) {
  // do nothing for now;  
};
```

**VariousImplementationFile.m**

```
#import "CommonBlocks.h"

(void)setup {
   testBlock(5);
 }
```

Unfortunately, when I try to push this code to iOS device I receive *error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*. It seems that I missing some.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Do you do it in the interface and implementation file ?

Comment: I give you an upvote as this is a good question. A lot of my friends keep asking me why they got this error. If someone is not so clear about linking process, it's very likely for him to get into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try add `static` keyword before the declaration:

```
static void (^testBlock)(int) = ^(int number) {
  // do nothing for now;  
};
```

Your code causes error because you have non-static variable testBlock declared in .h header file.

When you call `#import "CommonBlocks.h"` in VariousImplementationFile.m, testBlock is declared once. Then you import CommonBlocks.h in some where else, testBlock is declared once more, so you'll get symbol duplicate error.

Comment: I am pleasured to accept this as right answer. I didn't receive errors anymore. Thank you very much for your cooperation and just want to mention that I am interested in how static block is iterating with passed object instances, created instances inside block and so on. Thank you once again!

Comment: This is a bad answer. This will create a *separate* variable called `testBlock` in *each implementation file*.

Comment: I know this creates _seperate_ variable in each object. Does this really matter? If some one wanna say that he must use extern variable instead, I would argue that doing so introduce that symbol in the symtab which is public can be accessed by other translation units. That has serious issue with security and packaging unless it is on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Declare block in CommonBlocks.h this way

```
typedef void (^RCCompleteBlockWithResult)  (BOOL result, NSError *error);
```

Then you may use in any method for example:

```
 -(void)getConversationFromServer:(NSInteger)placeId completionBlock:(RCCompleteBlockWithResult)completionBlock
```

Comment: Hello, if I understand your answer, you mean to pass block to method and use it as type of "callback". But this is not the question. I am asking for one time block definition (with block body and so on) in one file and ping this block from different places in my application.

Answer (score -1):

This is not specific to blocks. Basically, you want to know how to have a global variable that is accessible from multiple files.

Basically, the issue is that in in C, each "symbol" can only be "defined" once (it can be "declared" multiple times, but just be "defined" once). Thus, you cannot put the "definition" of a symbol in a header file, because it will be included in multiple source files, so effectively, the same symbol will be "defined" multiple times.

For a function, the prototype is declaration, and the implementation with the code is the definition. You cannot implement a function in a header file for this reason. For a regular variable, writing the name and type of the variable is defining it. To only "declare" it, you need to use `extern`.

It is also worth mentioning `static`. `static` makes a variable *local to a particular source file*. That way, its name won't interfere with variables with the same name elsewhere. You can use this to make global variables that are "private" to a particular file. However, that is not what you are asking for -- you are asking for the exact opposite -- a variable that is "public", i.e. shared among files.

The standard way to do it is this:

**CommonBlocks.h**

```
extern void (^testBlock)(int); // any file can include the declaration
```

**CommonBlocks.m**

```
// but it's only defined in one source file
void (^testBlock)(int) = ^(int number) {
  // do nothing for now;  
};
```